# What is the source for the saying "כבד את השם בגרונך"?

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara

What is the source for the saying "כבד את השם בגרונך" in the Gemara?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! In general adding information that you know about the topic is very helpful. For example, you could edit in a brief description of the intent of the statement in question.

Comment: Why would you think the Gemara says this at all? Most Hebrew phrases are not in the Gemara. Can you [edit] in what you know about this phrase that you think it's in the Gemara? Have you heard it before? In what context? Did you see it written somewhere? Where?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.149.6 רֽוֹמְמ֣וֹת קל בִּגְרוֹנָ֑ם https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.58.1 קְרָ֤א בְגָרוֹן֙

Comment: @DoubleAA maybe this is where he heard it is from the Gemora https://www.chabad.org/1744438/ (maybe it is not the Rebbe who says the word Gemora)

Answer (score 8):

This is popularly attributed to Hazal, however it is not found in extant works of Hazal. Rather, our earliest source for this, is Rashi. [i]

The verse in Proverbs ([3:9](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2803.htm)) states:

> כַּבֵּד אֶת-יְהוָה, מֵהוֹנֶךָ;    וּמֵרֵאשִׁית, כָּל-תְּבוּאָתֶךָ
>
> Honour the LORD with thy substance, and with the first-fruits of all thine increase (Trans. JPS)

Rashi there states:

> מהונך - מכל מה שחננך אפי' מקול ערב (אל תקרי מהונך אלא מגרונך)
>
> From thy substance - from all that God granted you, even a sweet voice - read not 'from thy sustenance', but 'from thy throat'.

---

[i] Notes to Piskei Hagrih Zonnenfeld: (T'fillah Uveit HaKnesset: 2).

Answer (score 1):

An older source for the same idea (than the [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Proverbs.3.9.1) above)
[Pisecta Rabosi 25](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesikta_Rabbati.25):

> **כבד את ה' מהונך** ממה **שחננך** נתן לך בן מול אותו נתן לך בית עשה מזוזה ומעקה נתן לך חצר עשה סוכה נתן לך צאן הפרש בכורות וראשית הגז נתן לך בהמה לא תחטא בהם אלא עשה מצות שלא תחרוש בשור וחמור ולא תרביע כלאים נתן לך כסף וזהב עשה בהם מצות עשר תעשר את כל מהו את כל אפילו ממונך....
>   דבר אחר **כבד את ה' מהונך** שאם היית בעל נוי שלא תטעה אחר הזנות אלא כבד יוצרך וירא ממנו וקלסהו בנוי שנתן לך כבד ה' מהונך.
>   דבר אחר  **בקולך** שאם היה קולך נאה והיית יושב בבית הכנסת עמוד **וכבד ה' בקולך**. חייא בן אחותו של רבי אליעזר הקפר היה קולו נאה והיה אומר לו חייא בני עמוד וכבד את ה' ממה שחננך. נבות היה קולו נאה והיה עולה לירושלים והיו כל ישראל מתכנסים לשמוע קולו פעם...
>   דבר אחר **כבד את ה' מהוניך** אמר רבי אליעזר כבד את רופאיך עד שלא תצטרך לו כבד את ה' מהוניך אם נתן לך שדה הפרש את המעשר ואם עשית כן וימלאו אסמיך שבע...

(Rabbi Nachman [quoted](https://www.sefaria.org/Likutei_Moharan.27.6.6) it, from the Ber Haitiv [53:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Ba'er_Hetev_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.53.14) )

---

It there is a similar idea in Pesikta Drrabi Kohana [10:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesikta_D'Rav_Kahanna.10.3).

> ד"א כבד את י"י מהונך (שם), שאם היה **קולך** ערב, פרוס את שמע ועבור לפני התיבה,

Comment: These sources don't use the exact phrase sought.

Comment: @DoubleAA you do not think the Pesikta is Rashi's source?

Comment: It might be. But the source for the OPs wording is apparently Rashi's elaboration.

Comment: @DoubleAA the bere haitive quotes the Pesikta also גרון, it seems there are 2 version of the Pesikta, one is קול and one is גרון

Comment: If you can show that there is a Girsa of Garon earlier than Rashi that would be a great answer.

Comment: I checked https://www.hebrewbooks.org/44486 and https://www.hebrewbooks.org/39324  both are קול